# Failing a Jenkins job on a condition

Tags: jenkins, shell-exec

The end goal is to search for all the files n sub-directories within a folder a on a Linux box for control m characters. If yes, do not proceed with the ANT build and fail the job. If not, proceed with the ANT build.

In a Jenkins job I write this script `outline of the script`:

Cd batch 
Grep -r "\r" > text-file \ to find ctrl m char and redirect to text file if so.

Then compare the content. If text file is empty build else fail the job.

If [-s] fail job else build.

1. Is this a good approach of using Linux script to achieve? If not what's the better way?
2. How to configure a Jenkins job using execute shell and to make the shell fail and the Jenkins job fail on condition ?

Thanks

Comment: if you exit your script with non zero value, Jenkin will treat it as failure.  What is the problem with that?

Comment: Yeah..I can use exit 1.This should do I guess. I intend to test on the production Jenkins job and see if that works. Thanks

Comment: _I intend to test on the production Jenkins job_ . Why?  It is better to run Jenkins on your local machine, test basic things .. then deploy.

Answer (score 3):

Option 1: Exit your scripts with non zero value. Jenkins, by default, detect this as failure.

Option 2:  Use [Console Parser plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Console+Parser+Plugin) for looking for error patterns.

Both can be combined with [Build failure analyser](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Failure+Analyzer)  for neat message to user.

Answer (score 1):

For those who still find it difficult to understand how and where to write exit with non-zero value. Below is a Jenkins pipeline script with a non-zero exit.

```sh
 pipeline{
    agent any
    
    stages{
        stage('Git Checkout'){
            steps{
                git branch: "${BRANCH}",
                credentialsId: 'github-cred', 
                url: 'https://github.com/exam105/some-repo.git'
                exit 1
            }
        }
        stage('Build Project'){
            steps{

            }        
        }
    } 
}
```

The **Build Project** stage will not run.